# Interpreting a formula tattoo

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, identification

I saw

[image]

on the Internet and I'm curious as to what compound is represented by it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The molecule seen in the tattoo is a protein-based mammalian hormone called **oxytocin**, commonly called "the love hormone" because it is involved in several aspects of sexual reproduction.

[image]
[Image Source](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/Oxytocin_with_labels.png/800px-Oxytocin_with_labels.png)

Comment: IUPAC Name ,and other highlights?