# Structural entity for the tattoo resembling spine surgery involving 6AL-4V ELI alloy

Tags: molecular-structure, alloy

I have very little background in chemistry, so forgive me if I sound ridiculous and uneducated.

I want to have a tattoo designed in honor if my spine surgery that I had. I think that molecular structures (I think that's what its called -- the hexagonal structure stuff?) look pretty cool and I'd like to look into getting something like that.

Anyways, I dug some stuff up and came up with the alloy that orthopedic implants are usually made of, [6AL-4V ELI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ti-6Al-4V). Now, this is where I get stupid. Do alloys have molecular compositions at all? And if so, what would this one look like? 
If I just sound dumb right now and there is none, is there an alternative structure that could be used?

Again, I'm sorry if this is a silly question and is just wasting time, but this surgery is something I'm really passionate about and I would really like to have something visual to represent it by.

Comment: No, alloys don't have molecular structure, only [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) at best. People obsessed with tattoos usually prefer [certain **organic** molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/989/interpreting-a-formula-tattoo) instead. Also, congrats on a successful surgery!

Comment: *a tattoo designed in honor if my spine surgery* <--- That threw me off. I'm not saying it's a "stupid" question...but I'm not quite sure I understand it...

Comment: No prob; do you want something compact, or elongated, say, hexagon chain along the spine?

Comment: @andselisk  "*People obsessed with tattoos usually prefer certain organic molecules instead.*" I wasn't aware that was a thing....besides, I'm marveling at how you managed to dig that up from Chem.SE :D

Comment: @paracetamol People want to imprint the stuff that makes them happy, or remind of something important. So molecules of drugs and hormones are the obvious choice. There was a related CSE question  on a tattoo resembling a steel alloy used for crossfit weights or something; a woman won a competition and decided to make a tattoo, so it's not all that uncommon:)

Comment: @andselisk Yup, I remember the steel-alloy-weight thingy. I also happen to remember one where the OP wanted to tattoo a molecule of LSD on her arm (think you might've seen that) ;)

Comment: @Julia 6AL-4V ELI alloy is mostly titanium, so maybe you can use it's [electron shell configuration](https://hif.wikipedia.org/wiki/file:Electron_shell_022_Titanium.svg) as a basis. Just an idea.

Comment: @andselisk Hang on...is the steel-alloy-weight thingy question still around? If so, I think that would make this post a duplicate...

Comment: @paracetamol I cannot find it anymore, probably deleted by OP. Still, this is a different alloy and case, so it would be *related* IMO.

Comment: @Julia In the meantime you can also find a decent tattoo master and ask this person for a concept art ([inspiration](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ti-6Al-4V&dcr=0&tbs=imgo:1,isz:lt,islt:vga&tbm=isch&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0psL7tLjWAhWiA5oKHcVMAmMQpwUIHw&biw=1218&bih=933&dpr=1)) you explain your situation. If something will look off to you, you can always edit your question here and post a piece of graphics for the discussion.

Comment: The idea of Andselisk seems great!

Comment: The alloy is a mixture of hcp and bcc titanium grains, stabilized by the small amounts of Al and V. I'm sure a good artist could figure something out with a few unit cells, but I'm not an artist.